# Почему значение immutable переменных иногда можно менять?

Tags: android, kotlin

Внизу пример где значение LiveData объекта меняется хотя везде сказано что значение immutable нельзя менять. Объясните что я не так понимаю.

```
    class RestaurantViewModel @Inject constructor(
    api: RestaurantApi
) : ViewModel() {
        private val restaurantsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Restaurant>>()
        val restaurants: LiveData<List<Restaurant>> = restaurantsLiveData //та часть которую я не понимаю. 
//то есть мы можем менять значение MutableLiveData и присваивая это значение по сути делаем LiveData меняемым?
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val restaurants = api.getRestaurants()
            delay(2000)
            restaurantsLiveData.value = restaurants
        }
    }
}
```

И почему нельзя было придумать что-то, что позволяло бы не создавать MutableLiveData а сразу передавать данные в LiveData?

Comment: MutableLiveData - даже переводится буквально ИЗМЕНЯЕМАЯ LiveData, в этом ответ на вопрос в заголовке. Выносить наружу можно и MutableLiveData, не обязательно дублировать как у Вас в примере, это скорее правило хорошего тона, чем что-то обязательное.

Comment: Что у вас здесь immutable? И вы уверены, что это java, а не kotlin?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Вопрос был почему LiveData (тот который нельзя менять) в пятой строке берет значение restaurantsLiveData

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ошибся, исправил, жду ответа

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov то есть непосредственно LiveData нельзя менять но можно через MutableLiveData (4 строка)?

Comment: Не через, а непосредственно сам `MutableLiveData`, который вы и присвоили ссылке `restaurants`. Не смотря на то, что номинально тип ссылки `LiveData` - фактически она указывает на объект `MutableLiveData` и поведение этого объекта определяет **его** тип, а не тип ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

`val` указывает переменной, что ссылка на объект неизменяемая. Но, с учётом одного из свойств ООП - [инкапсуляции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) (объект может изменять своё содержимое изнутри), значение там не одинаковое.

`MutableLiveData` - как уже отметили, сама за себя говорит - я изменяюсь. Но не сама MutableLiveData изменяется, а её содержимое в классе, которое оно возвращает.

Более простой вариант инкапсуляции:

```kotlin
// делаем в классе мутабельную переменную
class Foo(var value: String)

object Bar {
   // создаём переменную, где не меняется ссылка
   val foo: Foo = Foo("something")
}

fun main() {
   // сохраним что-бы потом проверить одинаковые ли объекты
   val preEditedValue = Bar.foo

   // значение меняется
   Bar.foo.value = "Test"
   // проверяем на Referential equality
   println(preEditedValue === Bar.foo)
}
```

Суть в том, что-бы сокрыть мутабельность данных для публичного доступа (например, в вашем примере View ничего не должна изменять напрямую в `MutableLiveData`) туда и отдаётся `LiveData`, что не даёт возможности изменять данные там, где этого быть и не должно. Это не что-то новое, например, в Kotlin'е над этим очень сильно задумались, начиная с коллекций - `MutableCollection`, `Collection`, заканчивая аналогом LiveData - `MutableStateFlow`, `StateFlow`.

Мутабельность никогда не должна выноситься в публичный доступ во избежания проблем. Контролировать поток данных проще в одном классе.

#### Возможное решение (я так например делаю)

Для ViewModel, я создаю абстрактный класс, где определено всё, что будет выноситься наружу:

```kotlin
abstract class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
   abstract val list: LiveData<List<String>>

   abstract fun addItem(item: String)
}
```

Потом создаю "интегрированную" версию ViewModel'и (обычно делаю её private):

```kotlin
fun MyViewModel(): MyViewModel = IntegratedMyViewModel()

private class IntegratedMyViewModel : MyViewModel() {
   override val list: MutableLiveData<List<String>> = MutableLiveData(listOf())
   override fun addItem(item: String) {
      list.value = list.value.toMutableList().apply { add(item) }
   }
}
```

Сахар в том, что по сути, мутабельность не выноситься наружу (по крайней мере, легально ты не сможешь получить доступ к мутабельной лайвдате).